# Approximation of continuous functions by polynomials

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, proof-verification, continuity

> Let $D$ be a compact set in $R^d$. Assume $f \in C(D)$ is such that $\int_D f(x) x^\alpha dx = 0$ for any multi-index $\alpha = (\alpha_1, ... \alpha_d)$. Show that $f(x) = 0$ for all $x ∈ D$.

This is a problem in the topic of approximation of continuous functions by polynomials. My procedure to solve this is as follows:
We know that any function $f \in C(D)$ can be approximated by a polynomial. If we substitute $p$ instead of $f$ in the integral i.e. $
\int_D p(x) x^\alpha dx = 0$, then we get an integral of a polynomial $
\int_D p_1(x) dx = 0$, where $p_1(x) = p(x) x^\alpha$. Since this is true for all $\alpha$, we can say that $p$, hence $f$, is $0$ for all $x$. Is this right? If not, what is the right way to proceed? Thank you very much.

Comment: Polynomials are dense in the continuous functions. So for any $f\in C(D)$, you can define a sequence of polynomials that converges to $f$ in $L^1$